# Clickable star next to my questions in my user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, bookmarks

Looking at my user page in SO, I can see a small star with a number underneath for each question of mine which has been "favorited". So far so good, but that star turns out to be clickable, and *clicking it does nothing*.

Is that a bug? I'm not an HTML expert, but peeking at the source indeed shows that the div showing the favorite count is *outside* the div with the onclick event which surrounds the other question statistics (votes, answers, views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the updated user profile these are now clickable so you can unfavorite them without leaving the page.

Answer (score 2):

It does highlight that there is a tooltip, but I believe you've correctly identified a UI inconsistency, as all other hand pointers *do* link somewhere.