# Mouse pointer turns to hand icon on tag score [Profile Page]

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-score

**RELATED**

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74036/mouse-pointer-turns-to-hand-icon-on-favorite-icon-profile-page
>
> [Clickable star next to my questions in my user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/clickable-star-next-to-my-questions-in-my-user-page)

User profiles page now includes tag scores, the score turns to a hand on hover. It's not an actionable item.

I figure if we're tracking one we're tracking another.

Comment: Your related post is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/clickable-star-next-to-my-questions-in-my-user-page

Comment: I related it because I used the same title :p ~ Edited to include both :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed on local, but may take a few days till it is deployed.

Comment: That was fast!!

Comment: It doesn't seem like the fix actually made it out to deployment. What happened?

Comment: @Spudley works here, which browser are you using and what are you doing?

Comment: @waffles: I'm using FF5. On my user profile on SO, looking at my questions, some have 'favourite' stars. These stars have a 'hand' mouse pointer, but are not clickable.