# Hand cursor whilst nothing happens when clicked

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mouse pointer turns to hand icon on favorite icon [Profile Page]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74036/mouse-pointer-turns-to-hand-icon-on-favorite-icon-profile-page)
>   [Clickable star next to my questions in my user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/clickable-star-next-to-my-questions-in-my-user-page)

On my user page I can see my questions posted. Also, when a question of mine is bookmarked one or more times, I see that beautiful star next to my question on the left.

My question is: why does the bookmark star show a hand cursor when hovered while nothing happens when you click it?

I'm using Chrome 9.

Thanks.